Power Automate Approval Flow - How to add a 3rd option to Everyone Must Approve
I have a flow that creates an Approval for whoever is identified in an Approver people-picker (multi-select).  The requirement is to send parallel requests to the Approvers, which it does.  BUT, the Approvers need to also be able to select "Cancel".  It looks like only the Requestor can do that for some reason.  Is there a way I can keep the Approvals parallel, AND add a 3rd response option?  Approve, Reject, Cancel?
The overall requirements are this:
The user fills out the SharePoint default form - Including a multi select People-Picker field.  Sometimes they will identify multiple Approvers.  When the item is ready for approval, my flow triggers and engages a Start and Wait for an Approval action.  I'm currently using the Approve/Reject - Everyone Must Approve type.  The reason I'm using this is because the Approvals need to go out to each Approver at the same time (parallel, NOT sequential).  If one Approver selects "Reject", that rejects the entire Request, and the flow ends.  BUT, it also requires each Approver to "Approve" before it can go to the Manager for his/her final Approval.  This works great, except the Approvers ALSO need the ability to Cancel.  That's where I'm stuck.  Only the Requestor can Cancel.  Can I add that function for the Approvers AND keep the parallel Approval action?
Thank you!

As answered in similar question - Power Automate Approval action - Can I replicate the "Approve/Reject - Everyone Must Approve" with custom responses?
Two are many ways how to achieve it - one I can recommend is following - tap into Dataverse table where approvals are stored. You can start approval Everyone must approve and create new flow that has a trigger When rows is added, modified or deleted that monitors responses - if any response is Rejected, cancel the approval process.
References:
Microsoft docs : Trigger flows when a row is added, modified, or deleted
Step-by-step article on approval request delegation
This approach requires premium license - without it, is very challenging to fulfill your requirements without "cutting corners" and compromising UX.
